# list updating when i make another click after a longpress

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner in flutter and dart and was following the [flutter tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#7).
I wanted to try to remove an item from Favourites page on long press of the heart icon.

The function is executing but the screen gets updated only when i interact 2nd time(a tap or anything) just after the long press. I am not able to figure out what is wrong here.

This is my code.

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Namer App',
        theme: ThemeData(
            useMaterial3: true,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.indigo),
            listTileTheme: const ListTileThemeData(
              iconColor: Colors.indigo,
            )),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var current = WordPair.random();

  void getNext() {
    current = WordPair.random();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  var favourites = <WordPair>[];
  void toggleFavorite(WordPair wordPair) {
    if (favourites.contains(wordPair)) {
      favourites.remove(wordPair);
    } else {
      favourites.add(wordPair);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget page;
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        page = GeneratorPage();
        break;
      case 1:
        page = FavouritesPage();
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError('no widget for $selectedIndex');
    }

    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: NavigationRail(
                extended: constraints.maxWidth >= 600,
                destinations: [
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    label: Text('Home'),
                  ),
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                    label: Text('Favourites'),
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                child: page,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class FavouritesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    var favourites = appState.favourites;

    if (favourites.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('No favourites yet.'),
      );
    }

    return ListView(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Text('You have '
              '${favourites.length} favourites:'),
        ),

        ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: favourites.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            var pair = favourites[index];
            return ListTile(
              leading: GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onLongPress: () {
                  appState.toggleFavorite(pair);
                },
              ),
              title: Text(pair.asLowerCase),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an easy solution to make it work .

- first turn **FavouritesPage** into **StatefullWidget** .
- then wrap `appState.toggleFavorite(pair);` with `setState((){});` .

Copy this code and Paste it and it will work :

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Namer App',
        theme: ThemeData(
            useMaterial3: true,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.indigo),
            listTileTheme: const ListTileThemeData(
              iconColor: Colors.indigo,
            )),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var current = WordPair.random();

  void getNext() {
    current = WordPair.random();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  var favourites = <WordPair>[];
  void toggleFavorite(WordPair wordPair) {
    if (favourites.contains(wordPair)) {
      favourites.remove(wordPair);
    } else {
      favourites.add(wordPair);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget page;
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        page = GeneratorPage();
        break;
      case 1:
        page = FavouritesPage();
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError('no widget for $selectedIndex');
    }

    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: NavigationRail(
                extended: constraints.maxWidth >= 600,
                destinations: [
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    label: Text('Home'),
                  ),
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                    label: Text('Favourites'),
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                child: page,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class FavouritesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FavouritesPage> createState() => _FavouritesPageState();
}

class _FavouritesPageState extends State<FavouritesPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    var favourites = appState.favourites;

    if (favourites.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('No favourites yet.'),
      );
    }

    return ListView(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Text('You have '
              '${favourites.length} favourites:'),
        ),

        ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: favourites.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            var pair = favourites[index];
            return ListTile(
              leading: GestureDetector(
                child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onLongPress: () {
                  setState((){appState.toggleFavorite(pair);});
                },
              ),
              title: Text(pair.asLowerCase),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the other screen (`GeneratorPage`) needs `toggleFavorite` as well to add new favourites to the list. I would very much like to understand what is wrong with this code and why